# How can I make OS X's bash expand $PWD to be case sensitive?

Tags: macos, terminal, bash

I am running OS X 10.8 on a MBP 2011. I use some bash-scripts for tasks like backups of remote servers. One of the scripts contains this snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$PWD" != /Users/myuser/Documents/Backup ]
then
    echo "Wrong path: $PWD"
    exit 0
fi
```

When I execute this script in `/Users/myuser/Documents/Backup` (note the upper case B), I get this response:

```
Wrong path: /Users/myuser/Documents/backup
```

For some reason, the `$PWD` gets expanded to a lower case name. How can I alleviate this? My filesystem is not case sensitive: both `cd Backup` and `cd backup` work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two choices really: convert `$PWD` to a consistent case before comparing to your other string (which should also have consistent case). Or drop case-sensitive comparisons.

Converting it to lower case before comparing:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `echo $PWD | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]` != /users/myuser/documents/backup ]
then
    echo "Wrong path: $PWD"
    exit 0
fi
```

Dropping case sensitive comparisons:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nocasematch
if [[ "$PWD" != /Users/myuser/Documents/Backup ]]
then
    echo "Wrong path: $PWD"
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: I used the second option. Hower I needed to use the [[ ]] syntax for it to work.

Comment: I fixed the syntax. Good catch.